# Fields are not saved on the record but receive email

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I have server side code, i want to save these fields to the table 'merchants'. The problem now the only thing i could do is to submit the form and get email, while this part is my main issue and cant seem to fix it. I did couple of debugs steps, to check from the table when running a sql query nothing is being inserted. Yet debugg on the browser no error found. I need some help with server side code so can both get an email and save the new data to the table when new merchants register to the form.

// php code

```
`<?php
session_start();

require_once(__DIR__ . '/sendEmails/vendor/autoload.php');

// Check if the form has been submitted
// Check if the form has been submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Retrieve form data
    $companyName = isset($_POST['company_name']) ? $_POST['company_name'] : '';
    $contactName = isset($_POST['contact_name']) ? $_POST['contact_name'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $phone_number = isset($_POST['phone_number']) ? $_POST['phone_number'] : '';
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';
    $city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '';
    $state = isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : '';
    $zip_code = isset($_POST['zip']) ? $_POST['zip'] : '';

    // Check if the email already exists in your database (replace with your own logic)
    $emailExists = checkIfEmailExists($email); // Implement this function according to your database setup

    if ($emailExists) {
        // Redirect to login.php if email already exists
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

    // Send registration email to the merchant
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.outlook.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'delegant@outlook.com';
    $mail->Password = '****';
    $mail->setFrom('gcizmandelegant@outlook.com', 'e-Shopper');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $contactName);
    $mail->Subject = 'Merchant Registration Successful';
    $mail->Body = 'Dear ' . $contactName . ',<br><br>Your merchant registration was successful.<br><br>Thank you!';
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Email could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        // Insert merchant data into the database
        function insertMerchantData($companyName, $contactName, $email, $phone_number, $address, $city, $state, $zip_code) {
    // Database connection settings (replace with your own database credentials)
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbName = 'ecommerce_store';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';

    try {
        // Create a new PDO instance
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // Prepare and execute the database query
        $query = "INSERT INTO merchants (company_name, contact_name, email, phone_number, address, city, state, zip_code) VALUES (:companyName, :contactName, :email, :phone_number, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([
            ':companyName' => $companyName,
            ':contactName' => $contactName,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':phone_number' => $phone_number,
            ':address' => $address,
            ':city' => $city,
            ':state' => $state,
            ':zip_code' => $zip_code
        ]);

        return true; // Return true if the data is inserted successfully
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Database error: " . $e->getMessage();
        return false; // Return false if there is an error inserting the data
    }
}

    }
}

// Function to check if the email already exists in the database
// Function to check if the email already exists in the database
function checkIfEmailExists($email) {
  // Database connection settings (replace with your own database credentials)
  $dbHost = 'localhost';
  $dbName = 'ecommerce_store';
  $dbUsername = 'root';
  $dbPassword = '';

  // Create a new PDO instance
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  // Prepare and execute a database query to check if the email exists
  $query = "SELECT * FROM merchants WHERE email = :email";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
  
  // Check if the query returned any rows
  if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // Email already exists
    return true;
  } else {
    // Email does not exist
    return false;
  }
}


?>`
```

Comment: You never call `insertMerchantData()`

Comment: And the function shouldn’t be embedded inside the code block like that. Either inline the code, or move the function out and call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the email and save the new data to the table at the same time when new merchants register to the form, check the below code.
I have stored $mail->send() function to a variable and then checked whether it returns true or false. If it true then data store function calls.

````
<?php
session_start();

require_once(__DIR__ . '/sendEmails/vendor/autoload.php');

// Check if the form has been submitted
// Check if the form has been submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Retrieve form data
    $companyName = isset($_POST['company_name']) ? $_POST['company_name'] : '';
    $contactName = isset($_POST['contact_name']) ? $_POST['contact_name'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $phone_number = isset($_POST['phone_number']) ? $_POST['phone_number'] : '';
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';
    $city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '';
    $state = isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : '';
    $zip_code = isset($_POST['zip']) ? $_POST['zip'] : '';

    // Check if the email already exists in your database (replace with your own logic)
    $emailExists = checkIfEmailExists($email); // Implement this function according to your database setup

    if ($emailExists) {
        // Redirect to login.php if email already exists
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

    // Send registration email to the merchant
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.outlook.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'delegant@outlook.com';
    $mail->Password = '****';
    $mail->setFrom('gcizmandelegant@outlook.com', 'e-Shopper');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $contactName);
    $mail->Subject = 'Merchant Registration Successful';
    $mail->Body = 'Dear ' . $contactName . ',<br><br>Your merchant registration was successful.<br><br>Thank you!';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $emailSent = $mail->send();

    if (!$emailSent) {
        echo 'Email could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
       $this->insertMerchantData($companyName, $contactName, $email, $phone_number, $address, $city, $state, $zip_code)
}

// Insert merchant data into the database
public function insertMerchantData($companyName, $contactName, $email, $phone_number, $address, $city, $state, $zip_code) {
    // Database connection settings (replace with your own database credentials)
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbName = 'ecommerce_store';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';

    try {
        // Create a new PDO instance
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // Prepare and execute the database query
        $query = "INSERT INTO merchants (company_name, contact_name, email, phone_number, address, city, state, zip_code) VALUES (:companyName, :contactName, :email, :phone_number, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([
            ':companyName' => $companyName,
            ':contactName' => $contactName,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':phone_number' => $phone_number,
            ':address' => $address,
            ':city' => $city,
            ':state' => $state,
            ':zip_code' => $zip_code
        ]);

        return true; // Return true if the data is inserted successfully
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Database error: " . $e->getMessage();
        return false; // Return false if there is an error inserting the data
    }
}

    }
}

// Function to check if the email already exists in the database
// Function to check if the email already exists in the database
function checkIfEmailExists($email) {
  // Database connection settings (replace with your own database credentials)
  $dbHost = 'localhost';
  $dbName = 'ecommerce_store';
  $dbUsername = 'root';
  $dbPassword = '';

  // Create a new PDO instance
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  // Prepare and execute a database query to check if the email exists
  $query = "SELECT * FROM merchants WHERE email = :email";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
  
  // Check if the query returned any rows
  if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // Email already exists
    return true;
  } else {
    // Email does not exist
    return false;
  }
}


?>```
````

Comment: i am sealing away with this answer, why it met my expectation it just saves to my lovely table within the database. Thanks so much mate, continue doing the great work. Yet i reference you from now on and others here on the forum.

Comment: I am glad that it worked out for you